# How to initialize a data type that doesn't have a default trait (such as IWICBitmapFrameEncode)?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, wic, windows-rs

I'm using the windows-rs, the official crate for Windows API.
Usually I have no problem with data object initialization, I can use several way to do it, for example:

```rust
    let bitmap = BITMAP::default(); //initialize a BITMAP object
```

or if it's a struct I could just fill in some values like this:

```rust
let prop1 = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES {
            dpiX: Default::default(),
            dpiY: Default::default(),
            ..Default::default()
        };
```

or there are functions to use to do the initialization, like in the follow code, I initialized 3 objects: factory, stream and encoder, all without any issue.

```rust
let factory: IWICImagingFactory = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory,None,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)?;
        let encoder = factory.CreateEncoder(&GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, &GUID_VendorMicrosoft)?;
        let stream: IWICStream = factory.CreateStream()?;
        stream.InitializeFromMemory(&output)?;
        encoder.Initialize(&stream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache)?;
```

But when it comes to this object: IWICBitmapFrameEncode, I have no clue. First of all, I have to initialize it, otherwise it can't be used, I can't just declare it like in c++ :

```
IWICBitmapFrameEncode *pFrameEncode = NULL; //this is enough for c++ but not for rust!
```

So here is what I tried:

```rust
let frame = IWICBitmapFrameEncode::default(); //default not found.
let frame: IWICBitmapFrameEncode = Default::default(); //default not found.
let frame = IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Initialize(&self, None); //Initialize method does exist,
//but it takes 2 parameters, the first one is &self which I cannot provide.
```

So I tried:

```rust
let frame: IWICBitmapFrameEncode;
frame.Initialize(None); // This way it only takes one parameter (which can be set to None) but the complier still complains: used binding `frame` isn't initialized.
```

I'm pretty sure this IWICBitmapFrameEncode it not a return value from some other function, So I can't initialize it that way either. So I'm stuck.

the definition of IWICBitmapFrameEncode :

```rust
pub struct IWICBitmapFrameEncode(pub ::windows::core::IUnknown);
impl IWICBitmapFrameEncode {
    #[doc = "*Required features: `\"Win32_System_Com_StructuredStorage\"`*"]
    #[cfg(feature = "Win32_System_Com_StructuredStorage")]
    pub unsafe fn Initialize<P0>(&self, piencoderoptions: P0) -> ::windows::core::Result<()>
```

also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmapframeencode

In c++, it's just two lines of code, All I'm trying to do is to do the same in rust. How can I transalte the following code in c++ to rust:

```
IWICBitmapFrameEncode *pFrameEncode = NULL; //initialization done!
hr = pEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pFrameEncode, NULL); //now it can be used to receive value!
```

Note : Before I can use CreateNewFrame to receive value, I have to initialize it first. I'm stuck with the initialize part.

If you are interested in the whole context of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to encode bitmap data to JPG data (with Direct2d interface)is all:

```rust
let factory: IWICImagingFactory = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory,None,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)?;
        let encoder = factory.CreateEncoder(&GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, &GUID_VendorMicrosoft)?;
        let stream: IWICStream = factory.CreateStream()?;
        stream.InitializeFromMemory(&output)?;
        encoder.Initialize(&stream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache)?;
        let frame: IWICBitmapFrameEncode = IWICBitmapFrameEncode::Initialize(&self as _, None); //not working
       // frame.Initialize(None); //not working
        let frameopt = Some(frame);
        encoder.CreateNewFrame(&frameopt as *const Option<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> as _, &mut None as _);
```

the "not working" part is the only problem for me.

My final code with IInspectable's help，it does pass the compiler, but there is a memory violation exception at frame.SetPixelFormat I trying to find out why. Looks like IInspectable's answer did help but I need time to fully verify it. For now I will accept his answer.

```rust
fn clipboard_bmp_to_jpg() -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unsafe {
        if (!OpenClipboard(None)).into() {
            println!("open error");
        }
        let bitmap = BITMAP::default();
        let hdl = GetClipboardData(2)?;
        let h_bmp = HBITMAP(hdl.0);
        let mut rst = GetObjectW(h_bmp, std::mem::size_of::<BITMAP>() as _, Some(&bitmap as *const BITMAP as _));
        println!("{},{}", rst, bitmap.bmWidth);
        println!("{},{}", bitmap.bmBitsPixel, bitmap.bmWidthBytes);
        let num_bytes = (bitmap.bmWidthBytes*bitmap.bmHeight) as usize;
        let mut pixels: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(num_bytes);
        pixels.set_len(num_bytes);
        let mut output: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(num_bytes);
        output.set_len(num_bytes);
        rst = GetBitmapBits(h_bmp, num_bytes as _, pixels.as_mut_ptr() as _);
        println!("{},{}", rst, num_bytes);
        let factory: IWICImagingFactory = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory,None,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)?;
        let encoder = factory.CreateEncoder(&GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, &GUID_VendorMicrosoft)?;
        let stream: IWICStream = factory.CreateStream()?;
        stream.InitializeFromMemory(&output)?;
        encoder.Initialize(&stream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache)?;
        let mut frame = None;
        let mut props = None;
        let rst2 = encoder.CreateNewFrame(&mut frame, &mut props);
        let frame = frame.ok_or(Error::from(E_FAIL))?;
        //let props = props.ok_or(Error::from(E_FAIL))?;
        //let frame: IWICBitmapFrameEncode = None.unwrap();
        //let frameopt = Some(frame);
        //let rst2 = encoder.CreateNewFrame(&frameopt as *const Option<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> as _, &mut None as _);
        if rst2.is_err() {
            println!("error CreateNewFrame");
        }
        let rst3 = frame.Initialize(None);
        if rst3.is_err() {
            println!("error Initialize");
        }
        frame.SetSize(bitmap.bmWidth as _, bitmap.bmHeight as _)?;
        frame.SetPixelFormat(&GUID_WICPixelFormatDontCare as *const GUID as _)?; //memory violation exception here
        let source = IWICBitmapSource::from_raw(pixels.as_mut_ptr() as _);
        let rect = WICRect {
            X: 0,
            Y: 0,
            Width: bitmap.bmWidth,
            Height: bitmap.bmHeight,
        };
        let rst4 = frame.WriteSource(&source, &rect as _);
        if rst4.is_err() {
            println!("error WriteSource"); 
        }
        frame.Commit()?;
        let rst5 = encoder.Commit();
        if rst5.is_err() {
            println!("error WriteSource");
        }

    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Where is `IWICBitmapFrameEncode` located?

Comment: I added the IWICBitmapFrameEncode definition from window-rs crate (the Initialize part) and the MS document link.

Comment: I meant where it is in windows-rs.

Comment: It's in the mod.rs file.

Comment: There are plenty of mod.rs files in windows-rs, what is its path?

Comment: C:\Users\olnw\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-0.48.0\src\Windows\Win32\Graphics\Imaging\mod.rs

Comment: I meant Rust path (`foo::bar::baz::IWICBitmapFrameEncode`), but from the path you gave I can deduce it is `windows::Win32::Graphics::Imaging::IWICBitmapFrameEncode`.

Comment: It looks like a COM interface, try creating it with `CoCreateInstance()`.

Comment: I can't use CoCreateInstance for this, I can't provde parameters to fit. In the c++ example, there is no CoCreateInstance used. I only use CoCreateInstance to create factory of direct2d, but not other interface.

Comment: IWICBitmapFrameEncode can only be created by IWICBitmapEncoder::CreateNewFrame https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapencoder-createnewframe

Comment: In c++, it's just two lines of code, I just want to do the same thing in rust.

IWICBitmapFrameEncode *pFrameEncode = NULL; //initialization done!
hr = pEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pFrameEncode, NULL); //now it can be used to receive value!

Comment: In order to use CreateNewFrame, you have initialize it first! that's the problem.

Comment: @Simon Mourier
 It is not the return value of CreateNewFrame but a parameter, a raw pointer. So I have to declare and initialize it first, before I call CreateNewFrame.

Comment: Of course it's a parameter but an *out* parameter, you don't have to "create" anything first (certainly not use CoCreateInstance), basically you just need to pass a pointer (to a pointer). I don't know rust too much so I can't help much more with rust semantics

Comment: If you have a fully compilable & reproducible code, I could help more https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I know how to pass a raw pointer to CreateNewFrame, but raw pointer doesn't come out of nowhere, you have to declare it with the right Type first. Not only that, you have to initialize it before you can use it. That's where the issue is.

Comment: @Simon Mourier
I edited the post, you can see the code above the where the issue occur. It's fully compilable until the issue described in this post occur.

Comment: You cannot create a (default) COM interface, but you don't have to, either. [`CreateNewFrame`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Imaging/struct.IWICBitmapEncoder.html#method.CreateNewFrame) takes an `Option`, and the common pattern is: `let mut frame = None; encoder.CreateNewFrame(&mut frame, None);`. I'll see if I can write up a full answer when I find time.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you! That's what I thought as well. I tried to call encoder.CreateNewFrame first, But I have to pass a pointer (inside an Option) to get IWICBitmapFrameEncode from it. Yes it's an Option so I can pass None to it, but if I pass None to it, how am I suppose to get the IWICBitmapFrameEncode I need?

Comment: `let frame = frame.unwrap()`, for example. Type inference will have that light up as the `IWICBitmapFrameEncode` you're looking to use.

Comment: @IInspectable
 let mut frame = None; you can't do this. CreateNewFrame won't allow that as parameter. You have to give it exact type. 
If you want to try, you can install windows-rs crate with the following feature enabled

Comment: [dependencies.windows]
version = "0.48"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_Graphics_Gdi",
    "Win32_Graphics_Imaging",
    "Win32_Graphics_Direct2D_Common",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_System_LibraryLoader",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
    "Win32_System_DataExchange",
    "Win32_System_Com_StructuredStorage"
]

Comment: No, that works. Type inference will pull all the pieces of the generic together. It's probably the second parameter that causes the compile to fail. Again, if I find a bit of time, I'll have a closer look. I probably have some WIC Rust code floating about here anyway...

Comment: The second parameter is optional, it can be None (cast as a raw pointer to cvoid). The problem is the first parameter. You have to declare and initiate it with the right type, not a general type. I'll know when you try it. Hope you find the time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM programming in Rust using the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate is both very convenient, as well as extremely hard to discover. COM interface pointers are modeled as `#[repr(transparent)]` tuple structs, holding a single `NonNull<c_void>` value. When used as `[out]` parameters, they are wrapped behind an `Option`, with the effect of having the same layout as a raw pointer, but with the inability to dereference a null pointer.

All of that is pretty solid design, at the expense of making it very challenging to discover how to play along said design's rules. When calling a COM interface method that returns an interface pointer, you'd typically create a `mut` variable with value `None`, pass it by `&mut`, handle errors, and `unwrap` (or handle the `None`-case). Type inference will generally be able to deduce the `T` in `Option<T>`, so you don't have to spell it out.

Assuming that you have a function `foo` that returns a [`Result<T>`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/type.Result.html) you can do the following:

```rust
fn foo() -> Result<()> {
    // ...
    unsafe { encoder.Initialize(&stream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache) }?;

    let (frame, props) = {
        // Initialize variables to `None` (i.e. null pointers)
        // `T` in `Option<T>` is inferred from the subsequent call
        let mut frame = None;
        let mut props = None;
        // Call COM method and propagate errors
        unsafe { encoder.CreateNewFrame(&mut frame, &mut props) }?;
        // "unwrap" the Option's and convert "null" pointers to errors
        let frame = frame.ok_or(Error::from(E_FAIL))?;
        let props = props.ok_or(Error::from(E_FAIL))?;
        // All set, so we can move the interface pointers out
        (frame, props)
    };

    // Use `frame` and `props` as needed

    // ...

    Ok(())
}
```

This compiles using `windows` v0.44.0. If this fails for a later version, let me know.

Comment: @abcjeff See [type coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html), specifically under [coercion types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) it explains that `&mut T` to `*mut T` is allowed to happen automatically. If you are getting an error, please show it.

Comment: Ok I mange to get it pass the compiler with this code, but there is panic and I'm trying locate the error. I'll get back to you when I finish.

Comment: @abcjeff The code presented here cannot panic. If your program panicks it's most likely that you're calling `CoUninitialize`. Even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize) says that you **must** call it for every successful call to `CoInitialize`, that's not actually true. Indeed, you should **never** call `CoUninitialize`, especially not when using objects with a `Drop` implementation.

Comment: I edited the original post with my final code, please take a look.

Comment: @abcjeff That's an unrelated issue, and you should [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of adding to this one. The one thing that looks very wrong is a huge, all-encompassing `unsafe { ... }` block. What that accomplishes is turning your Rust code into C, inheriting all memory safety issues along with it.

Comment: Are you sure it's unrelated? memory violation exception at frame.SetPixelFormat after the frame that is created by your code. I'm not sure it's properly initialized. I will make my code look better later. This is only the first stage. At this stage I'm only test things out.

Comment: @abcjeff Yes, it's unrelated. The code presented here is safe and sound. There's no path through the code that will surface an invalid pointer, evidenced by the fact that several calls into the interface represented by `frame` succeed, prior to a call failing. That call, incidentally, does a lot of pointer casting. Specifically, the cast from `*const T` into `*mut T` won't end well.

Comment: It's not that simple. I comment out the the frame.SetPixelFormat line, because it's optional anyway. The code still crash with memory violation at the later frame.WriteSource which doesn't has complicate cast.

Comment: @abcjeff There are *lots* of issues with the code, but none of them trace back to the code provided in this answer. `unsafe` Rust is hard to get right, and the first order of action should be to limit `unsafe` to *only* those sections of code that actually are. That allows you (and others) to more quickly see where things can go wrong.

Comment: I understand, I will rewrite it entirely. Actually most code in my app is safe. This function is an exception because it deals with the API so much I have to make it unsafe. But I will see what I can do make it partially unsafe so that I can debug better. I will also read again the MS document to find the proper way to do this. Thank you so much for your advice.